# Tinymce autocompleter make non case sensitive

Tags: jquery

I am using the tinymce plugin, autocomplete to list values and replace text as follows:

```
        setup: function (editor) {
            /* An autocompleter that allows you to insert special characters */
            editor.ui.registry.addAutocompleter('text_responses', {
              ch: '/',
              minChars: 1,
              columns: 'auto',
              fetch: function (pattern) {
                var matchedChars = text_responses.filter(function (char) {
                  return char.name.indexOf(pattern) !== -1;
                });

                return new tinymce.util.Promise(function (resolve) {
                  var results = matchedChars.map(function (char) {
                    return {
                      value: char.replacement,
                      text: char.name,
                      icon: char.name
                    }
                  });
                  resolve(results);
                });
              },
              onAction: function (autocompleteApi, rng, value) {
                editor.selection.setRng(rng);
                editor.insertContent(value);
                autocompleteApi.hide();
              }
            });
        }
```

My array of values in `text_responses` contains phrases that start uppercase, but i want to allow the above to search using both upper and lower case.

I've tried adding `.toLowerCase()` on `char.name` and `pattern` but neither worked.

Comment: Can you share an example of `text_responses` values?

Comment: sure, it looks like `[{"name":"one","replacement":"1"}, {"name":"Two","replacement":"2"}]` so i want to have it pickup the values no matter if its caps or not. current if you we're to type `One` nothing would show because its a lower `o` and if you were to type `Two` that wouldn't show either because it's a capital `T` - I guess the easiest way would be make the search value lower case and the JSON all lower case but I don't know how to change the search value to be lowercase in the above for the tinymce plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to lower case the `pattern` and the `char.name`.

```
var matchedChars = text_responses.filter(function (char) {
  return char.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
});
```